# Understanding python close method

Tags: python

Is it correctly understood that the following two functions do the exact same? No matter how they are invoked.

```
def test():
    file = open("testfile.txt", "w")
    file.write("Hello World")

def test_2():
    with open("testfile.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("Hello World")
```

Since python invokes the close method when an object is no longer referenced.

If not then this quote confuses me:

> Python automatically closes a file when the reference object of a file
>   is reassigned to another file. It is a good practice to use the
>   close() method to close a file.

from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_close.htm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the `close` method would be invoked by python garbage collector (finalizer) machinery in the first case, and immediately in the second case. If you loop calling your `test` or `test_2` functions thousands of times, the observed behavior could be different.

[File descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) are (at least on Linux) a precious and scarce resource (when it is exhausted, the [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) syscall fails). On Linux use [getrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html)  with `RLIMIT_NOFILE` to query the limit on the number of file descriptors for your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)). You should prefer the [close(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) syscall to be invoked quickly once a file handle is useless.

Your question is implementation specific, operating system specific, and computer specific. You may want to understand more about operating systems by reading [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

On Linux, try also the `cat /proc/$$/limits` or `cat /proc/self/limits` command in a terminal. You would see a line starting with `Max open files` (on my Debian desktop computer, right now in december 2019, the soft limit is 1024). See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Answer (score 2):

No. The first one will not save the information correctly. You need to use `file.close()` to ensure that file is closed properly and data is saved.

On the other hand, `with` statement handles file operations for you. It will keep the file open for as long as the program keeps executing at the same indent level and as soon as it goes to a level higher will automatically close and save the file.

More information [here](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html).

Comment: would you explain why the information being saved with the first method is incorrect?

Comment: I might be incorrect, but the `close` only closes the file handler. The data should already be written to the file.

Comment: if the file is not closed correctly the file can get corrupted and the info inside the file will be lost, that is why it is advisable to use the `with` statement, because it closes the file properly, automatically for you so you do not have to worry about it

Comment: @maestro.inc Yes, not invoking `close()` is a bad practice but the `write()` method still saves whatever you need to save to the file. I just think that the first statement isn't accurate enough

Comment: The data is written to the file and save, yes, but if the file is closed wrongly the data in the file can get corrupted in which case it is still lost anyways, besides not using with just makes your code somewhat unnecessarily longer than it could be

Comment: does the Python `write()` function block until the data is synced to disk (ie. is it specified that the underlying C function must use `O_SYNC` or `O_DSYNC`) ? Does `close()` block? And, is this behavior different when these actions are performed implicitly by the context manager?

Answer (score 1):

In case of `test` function, `close` method is not called until Python garbage collector will `del f`, in this case it's invoked by file `__del__` magic method which is invoked on variable deletion.

In case of `test_2` function, `close` method is called when code execution goes outside of `with` statement. Read more about python context managers which is used by `with` statement.

```
with foo as f:
    do_something()
```

roughly is just syntax sugar for:

```
f = foo.__enter__()
do_something()
f.__exit__()
```

and in case of file, `__exit__` implicitly calls `close`

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correctly understood. The `close` method is invoked via the `__exit__` method, which is only invoked when exiting a `with` statement not when exiting a function. Se code example below:

```
class Temp:
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        print('exited')

    def __enter__(self):
        pass
    
def make_temp():
    temp = Temp()

make_temp()
print('temp_make')
with Temp() as temp:
    pass
print('temp_with')
```

Witch outputs:

> temp_make
>
> exited
>
> temp_with